# Is it possible to create annotation which would check if user is authenticated? Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations

I am writing an app, and some parts of it require the user to be authenticated. Is it possible to write an annotation for a method, which would check user status, and depending on it either function would be called or it would navigate to the login screen -> if login success it will come back and call the function? like this:

```
@RequiresAuth
fun commentOnTask(){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Annotations don’t do anything themselves. They provide you a way to do things using reflection. This is not a case where they would help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, by this time I could not find a way of how to do it with annotation.

The only workaround is to use such a pattern https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-login-navigation/index.html?index=..%2F..index#9